# how add image to firestore in flutter image picker

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I want add photo to firestore. Can you please tell me how to do that?

I am using image picker to pick photo in my flutter app.

My code is below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onlinecity/component/TextField/inputField.dart';



import 'package:onlinecity/component/Button/roundedButton.dart';
import 'package:onlinecity/component/Button/textButton.dart';
import 'style.dart';
import 'package:onlinecity/theme/style.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class AddOfferScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  AddOfferScreenState createState() => new AddOfferScreenState();
}

class AddOfferScreenState extends State<AddOfferScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool _autovalidate = false;
  String _productTitle;
  String _category;
  String _contactNumber;
  Future<File> _imageFile;

  void _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }

  _onPressed() {
    print("button clicked");
  }

  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(value)));
  }

  bool _handleSubmitted() {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  void validateAndSubmit() async{
    if (_handleSubmitted()){
      try {
        Firestore.instance.collection('todos').document().setData({"productTitle":_productTitle,"category":_category,"contactNumber":_contactNumber});

      }
      catch (e){
        print('Error: $e');
      }
    }

  }

  void _showaddphoto(){
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(
      actions: <Widget>[
        new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.camera_alt), onPressed: () => _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.camera),
          tooltip: 'Take a Photo'),
        new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.sd_storage), onPressed:  () => _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.gallery),
          tooltip: 'Pick Image from gallery')

      ],
    );
    showDialog(context: context,child: dialog);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //print(context.widget.toString());
    return new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(image: backgroundImage),
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new SizedBox(
                    height: screenSize.height / 2 + 20,
                    child: new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(
                          "CREATE ACCOUNT",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: headingStyle,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        autovalidate: _autovalidate,
                        //onWillPop: _warnUserAboutInvalidData,
                        child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new FutureBuilder<File>(
                              future: _imageFile,
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                                    snapshot.data != null) {
                                  return new Image.file(snapshot.data);
                                } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
                                  return const Text('error picking image.');
                                } else {
                                  return const Text('You have not yet picked an image.');

                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            new RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: _showaddphoto, icon: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo), label: new Text('Add Photo')),

                            new InputField(
                              hintText: "product title",
                              obscureText: false,
                              textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                              textStyle: textStyle,
                              textFieldColor: textFieldColor,
                              icon: Icons.person_outline,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              bottomMargin: 20.0,
                              validateFunction: (value)=> value.isEmpty ? 'UserName can\'t be empty' : null,
                              onSaved: (value)=> _productTitle = value,
                            ),

                            new InputField(
                              hintText: "Category",
                              obscureText: false,
                              textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              textStyle: textStyle,
                              textFieldColor: textFieldColor,
                              icon: Icons.mail_outline,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              bottomMargin: 20.0,
                              validateFunction: (value)=> value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null,
                              onSaved: (value)=> _category = value,
                            ),
                            new InputField(
                              hintText: "Contact Number",
                              obscureText: true,
                              textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                              textStyle: textStyle,
                              textFieldColor: textFieldColor,
                              icon: Icons.lock_open,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              bottomMargin: 40.0,
                              validateFunction: (value)=> value.isEmpty ? 'Contact number can\'t be empty' : null,
                              onSaved:  (value)=> _contactNumber = value,
                            ),
                            new RoundedButton(
                                buttonName: "Continue",
                                onTap: validateAndSubmit,
                                width: screenSize.width,
                                height: 50.0,
                                bottomMargin: 10.0,
                                borderWidth: 1.0)
                          ],
                        )),
                    new TextButton(
                      buttonName: "Terms & Condition", onPressed: _onPressed,buttonTextStyle: buttonTextStyle,)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no code below.

Comment: Code added please check

Answer (score 3):

```
  import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

  /////////

        var fileName = "fileName.jpeg";
  StorageUploadTask putFile =
      storage.ref().child("folder/$fileName").putFile(_image);
  putFile.future.catchError(onError);

  UploadTaskSnapshot uploadSnapshot = await putFile.future;

  print("image uploaded");

  Map<String, dynamic> pictureData = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  pictureData["url"] = uploadSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString();


  DocumentReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection("collection").document(fileName);

  await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    await transaction.set(collectionReference, pictureData);
    print("instance created");
  }).catchError(onError);
```

Here, this will put file to storage, and then save downloadUrl to your collection. instead of `document(fileName)` you can choose your own document ID.

Comment: where do I put this, i want sent file to storage and then the save the url to my cloud firestore

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) and write only its reference to Cloud Firestore.
Cloud Firestore isn't for saving media like images, sounds or movies.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend uploading the image to cloud storage.
You can then download the url and upload the url to firestore.

Here's the code to upload an image to storage.

```
Future uploadFiles(File file) async {
  try {
    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('Images/image.png').putFile(file);
    print("Successfully upload file ${i + 1}");
  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print('error is ${e.message}');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Following code has use [ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package from pub.dev

To store the image in firestore you can convert the image to a string

First import following package

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
```

Then use follwing code

Get image from storage using ImagePicker class

```
ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery,
  maxHeight: 200,
);
```

Then convert image to base64 based String

```
String encodedImageString = base64.encode(File(pickedFile.path).readAsBytesSync().toList());
```

**Note:** *pickedFile.path* is path of file selected from storage
Also, encode method requires List which can be done by using -> *readAsBytesSync().toList()*

Once you have image in string you can store it into firestore as follow

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).set(company.toDocument()), SetOptions(merge: true));
```

toDocument() is a method define in my model class to convert object in Map object see below

```
class Company extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String logo;

  Company({
      this.id,
      @required this.name,
      @required this.logo,
      });

  Company copyWith({
      String id,
      String name,
      String logo,
    }) {
    return Company(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      logo: logo ?? this.logo,
    );
  }

  static Company fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    return Company(
      id: snap.id,
      name: snap.get('name'),
      logo: snap.get('logo'),
    );
  }

  Map<String, Object> toDocument() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'logo': logo,
    };
  }
}
```

And to convert encodedImageString into Image you can use the following code

```
Image.memory(base64.decode(encodedImageString))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get image from gallery

```
File? _image;
final _picker = ImagePicker();
var imgValue;

Future getImageFromGallery() async {

   final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
   final File image = File(pickedFile!.path);
   //  File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

   setState(() {
     _image = image;
   });
}
```

Then upload image on firestore:

```
Future uploadImageToFirebase() async {

   String fileName = basename(_image!.path);

   FirebaseStorage firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance;

   Reference ref =firebaseStorageRef.ref().child('upload/$fileName'+ DateTime.now().toString());
   
// FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
   UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image!);
   
   uploadTask.then((res) {res.ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) => imgValue = value);});
}
```