# Firestore databse, upload and download files

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I want to create button which will allow me to upload images to specific database collection, I manually created a collection and added some random pictures there which I'm using for slider in the app.
Here is code for fetching them from this database:

```
  initSliderImages() async {
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('slider_images');
    result.snapshots().listen((data) {
      List imgs = [];
      data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        var imageData = change.doc.data();
        String image = imageData['url'];
        imgs.add(CachedNetworkImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, imageUrl: image));
      });

      setState(() {
        images = imgs;
      });
    });
  }
```

And here is Slider code:

```
  sList images = [];
  Widget slider() {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 200.0,
        width: fullWidth(context),
        child: (images != null && images.length > 0)
            ? Carousel(
                images: images,
                dotSize: 3.0,
                dotSpacing: 10.0,
                dotColor: Colors.red,
                indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                dotBgColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                // dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: true,
                moveIndicatorFromBottom: 180.0,
                noRadiusForIndicator: true,
              )
            : JumpingDotsProgressIndicator(
                fontSize: 40.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So I want to create button which will alow me to upload images to this database collection, and also to alow me to remove them from database collection, maybe in some other page to create grid view which will display images from this database collection, and to be able to remove image from them.

Comment: Is your issue when trying to display the button? Or uploading and removing the images once the button for each action is clicked? I would suggest having a look at this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/uploading-images-to-cloud-storage-using-flutter-130ac41741b2) and this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461745/how-add-image-to-firestore-in-flutter-image-picker), and also this other about the [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602877/flutter-can-someone-help-me-get-this-post-button-to-execute)

Comment: @Sergi I want to make function which will allow me to upload image to this specific firebase collection 'slider_images' [first code up].. And also to make some simple page which will fetch this images where i will be able to remove them from collection, to not need every time to go database.

Comment: Pardon, could you rephrase that? The collection is in the database, correct? I understand you likely have 2 databases: one that has the image data (the url seems to be what you're using) and one that has the image itself (what the url is pointing to, if I'm not mistaken), so would you mind clarifying what you mean when you state "be able to remove them from the collection, and not need to go the database every time"? Do you mean not have to go into the GUI? Because modifying the collection involves entering the database, if I'm understanding this correctly. (EDIT: typo)

Comment: Hello, so i have collection created in database, and i added there some images, and i created function in the app to fetch this images from this collection and to display them in slider, so i want to create now button with function when i want to upload some image to this collection to not need to every time in databse and to add there image maualy, so i want to create button to pick image from galery, and when i pres upload then to this automaticly save to this collection in databse, and app will automaticly fetch this new image and display in slider...

Comment: 2. also to create function where i will be able to remove images from this collection to not need every time to user computer and to go to database to delete image from there

Comment: Regarding your issue on how to delete the images correctly, I found a similar question with an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175316/12512650) which did that.  
As a side note I would like to encourage you to divide this issue into 2 questions since it seems like you are trying to fix 2 issues here which can make it confusion for people who might read this question in the future.